# Heroku - Problem with deploying site for the first time || Code=H10

Tags: javascript, heroku, deployment, backend, web-deployment

as the title says - I'm trying to deploy a website to Heroku for the first time. I changed all ports to Process.env.PORT || 3001 ( 3001 is the default one ).

I'm receiving this error upon running `heroku logs --tail`

[image: terminal error]

Also I have a procfile with the following data in it

```
web: node backend/index.js // server index.js is in backend folder
```

and here's my Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "marketapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.3",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.10",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^13.5.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.2.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.13.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "server": "node public/index.js",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run start\""
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^7.1.0",
    "netlify-cli": "^9.16.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: "I changed all ports to Process.env.PORT || 3001"—note that `process.env` ≠ `Process.env`. Case is important. And I'm not sure what you mean by "all ports", but this port should only be used for the port your application binds to. Database ports, for example, should not be set to this value. Having said all that... your error doesn't appear to have anything to do with the port you're binding to.

Comment: The error says [the `request-promise` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) can't be found, which is not surprising since you haven't declared it as a dependency. Make sure to include all dependencies in your `package.json` and `package-lock.json` or `yarn.lock`. (Side note, that module is deprecated. I suggest you update your application to remove that dependency.)

Comment: Yep , I just noticed that too.. It fixed the problem, thank you